# Imaginary margin in IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

[image]

Does anyone know why the image is not aligned to the bottom right of the container where it should be, but instead has some sort of imaginary margin which causes it to overlap the button?

This occurs *only* in IE8, view the page in any other browser and it looks super.

[**Live example for your inspection.**](http://suchen.mobile.de/auto-inserat/mercedes-benz-c-220-cdi-t-modell-avantgarde-avantgarde-autom-sulz-am-neckar/157995215.html)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the css at line 1616 to "text-align:right" should fix it.

```
.dealerLogo {
   text-align: right;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know *why* this is happening, and I didn't try hard enough to find out.

To workaround the problem, on `.vcard .dealerImages .dealerLogo` change `text-align: center` to `text-align: right`. This doesn't make any difference in other browsers, but fixes IE8.

You'll also need to add `z-index: 1` to `.vcard .dealerImages .dealerContact`, to keep the rightmost part of the orange button working.

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to answer this, both answers are correct but I must perform my StackOverflowly duty and tick the first correct one :)